# firmware crash qca6174 hw2.1

Tags: drivers, wireless, network-manager, crash, atheros

Everytime my laptop goes to sleep (low battery), wireless adapter crashes. This makes the system completly unusable. I cannot remove the driver, kill it, or restart NetworkManager. I cannot reboot neither.

```
[40164.539367] wlp7s0: deauthenticating from 1a:5b:0e:ed:a3:9d by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[40164.790817] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid a6543dc3-4488-4dd3-8907-d3d69f6810ab)
[40164.790837] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: qca6174 hw2.1 target 0x05010000 chip_id 0x003405ff sub 105b:e08e
[40164.790844] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[40164.792107] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: firmware ver SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 5 features ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 10bf8e08
[40164.792763] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 ae2e275a
[40164.792771] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
...a very long stacktrace below...


denis:~ $ ps ax | grep ath10
  783 ?        S<     0:00 [ath10k_wq]
  784 ?        S<     0:00 [ath10k_aux_wq]
23090 pts/2    D+     0:00 sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
23381 ?        D      0:00 sudo rmmod ath10k_pci
23564 ?        D      0:00 sudo pkill ath10k_pci
23951 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto ath10


/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174 $ ls
hw2.1  hw3.0
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1 $ sha256sum firmware-5.bin 
cc77874b709e26ffcc1cd548a4813e4be8cd523329c1b3ba34e341417d2935c5  firmware-5.bin

/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1 $ uname -a
Linux denis-Aspire-VN7-791G 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 $ lshw -c network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 20
       serial: ac:d1:b8:4e:2d:05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.10.0-38-generic firmware=SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.43.156 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:36 memory:d1400000-d15fffff

$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2

$ iwconfig
docker0   no wireless extensions.

wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Honor 10"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point: A4:93:3F:99:75:94   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:68   Missed beacon:0

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I need to find a way to fix it either with a new driver, or patching the existing one. Any suggestions?.. Maybe an easy fix?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `iwconfig; cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Comment: The 4.10 kernel is unsupported for at least a year, install  the newest 4.4 or 4.15 kernel

Comment: @Jeremy31 upgrading kernel to 4.15.45 seems to have solved the problem; thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my case (Ubuntu 18.04.3, qca6174 hw2.1 firmware) the problem was not solved with kernel 4.15, nor did kernel 5 solve it.

After tearing my hair for 2 days, I was able to solve the problem with an older firmware qca6174 version.

I was not able to unload the ath10k_pci module before suspend automatically, not via a systemd Unit nor with a script in /lib/systemd/system/system-sleep.
Installing the newest qca6174 formware also did not help.

What helped was an older firmware version from 2016!
Now I have qca6174 hw2.1 version 141 installed, although my notebook runs on 18.04.3 with Kernel 5.

I got that tip from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/978385/1004167 so I got the firmware from there: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/linux-firmware/1.157 and copied the ath10k_pci/QCA6174/hw2.1 files (which my card is using) into my /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1 folder.

After a reboot, I did not have to unload the driver before suspend (removed my scripts).

Going to sleep and resume works for me now, as it did before upgrading from 16.04.
The only thing I have to see now is, how to prevent the copied files from being overwritten by an upgrade.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me :)